# How to change file name?

Tags: php

I have a software which has different folders with php files in it.I would like to change these file names in all folders.Examples I have a file name appointment.php now i would like to change it to appoint.php in all related php files and folders.How can i do that.Changing it manually will take lot of time.I have in all 100 files in which i need to change.I need a code or method which changes this in all files and folders.please overlook my English if mistakes done

```
appointment.php to `appoint.php`
```

Answer (score 0):

Renames a file or directory

```
<?php

 rename ("/folder/appointment.php", "/folder/appoint.php");

?>
```

Comment: i would like to change offline on wamp server.this appointment.php is in atleast 50 php files as codes

Comment: @user3500328 i think you want to change filename in folder within a folder. right?

Comment: yes.now this appointment.php act as part of code in other php files

Answer (score 0):

since your trying to rename many file i think this software can help you

http://www.advancedrenamer.com/download